# mypy doesn't understand class and interface are the same

Tags: python, interface, mypy

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class IState(ABC):
    """Interface para o padrão de projeto State."""

    @abstractmethod
    def sucesso_ao_pagar(self) -> None:
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def despachar_pedido(self) -> None:
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def cancelar_pedido(self) -> None:
        pass


class Pedido:
    """Classe que representa um pedido."""

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.estado_atual = AguardandoPagamentoState(self)

    def realizar_pagamento(self) -> None:
        self.estado_atual.sucesso_ao_pagar()

    def despachar(self) -> None:
        self.estado_atual.despachar_pedido()

    def cancelar(self) -> None:
        self.estado_atual.cancelar_pedido()

    def set_estado_atual(self, estado_atual: IState) -> None:
        self.estado_atual = estado_atual

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.estado_atual)


class AguardandoPagamentoState(IState):
    """Estado inicial do pedido."""

    def __init__(self, meu_pedido: Pedido):
        self.pedido = meu_pedido

    def sucesso_ao_pagar(self) -> None:
        print("Pedido pago com sucesso!")
        self.pedido.set_estado_atual(PagoState(self.pedido))

    def despachar_pedido(self) -> None:
        print("Pedido não pode ser despachado, pois não foi pago!")

    def cancelar_pedido(self) -> None:
        print("Pedido cancelado com sucesso!")
        self.pedido.set_estado_atual(CanceladoState(self.pedido))
```

This code works fine, but when i run mypy, it states:

`Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "IState", variable has type "AguardandoPagamentoState")  [assignment]mypy`

Why is it generating this problem, given that the AguardandoPagamentoState class implements the IState interface?

If I put a comment like

```
# type: ignore
```

it stops throwing this error, but I want to know how solve this.
Mypy should understand the class relation

Comment: Where is the error?  I don't see an actual line of code in the error.

Comment: The class and interface are *not* the same. The class is just one of possibly many classes that implement the interface. If it were the only class, there'd be no reason to define a separate abstract base class in the first place.

Comment: The error is here (class Pedido):

def set_estado_atual(self, estado_atual: IState) -> None:
        self.estado_atual = estado_atual

estado_atual was already defined as AguardandoPagamentoState in init, so mypy was showing the describbed error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you establish a static type of `AguardandoPagamentoState` for the attribute in `Pedido.__init__`:

```
def __init__(self) -> None:
    self.estado_atual = AguardandoPagamentoState(self)
```

But then you try to relax that by allowing *any* value of type `IState` to be assigned to it in `set_estado_atual`:

```
def set_estado_atual(self, estado_atual: IState) -> None:
    self.estado_atual = estado_atual
```

`AguardandoPagamentoState` may implement the interface, but not all types that implement the interface are `AguardandoPagamentoState` or subclasses thereof. You need to establish the more general static type explicitly:

```
def __init__(self) -> None:
    self.estado_atual: IState = AguardandoPagamentoState(self)
```